# Make div disappear when reducing window width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do you make a div disappear when reducing window width, leaving it's complete space available to other elements? I do not mean hiding piece by piece on overflow, but the whole element.

I came across this brilliant feature on the following URL:
http://flexslider.woothemes.com

Is javascript required or can it be done with CSS? I noticed the page is pretty much HTML5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with just CSS:

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  .mydiv { display: none; }
}
```